# When consuming an avro schema object from kafka in a springboot application and then storing the message in a database do I need a mapping class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro

I have a springboot application that will be listening to a Kafka topic which is passing messages that conform to an avro schema. The springboot app will be responsible for taking these messages from kafka and storing them in a postgres database. The fields on the kafka message map almost 1 to 1 to the database columns.

The way it's coding right now we have a mapper class that will deserialized avro object and map that to a POJO and then use that POJO to map to the db. This all feels very manual the way it's written right now and I guess I'm just wondering if it's actually needed or if there is some Spring/Avro auto-magical way of doing this? This is the code in our mapper class to give you some sense of what I'm referring to:

```
public class AppointmentMapper {

    final static String NO_DESCRIPTION="";
    final static String NO_FACILITY="";

    public static AppointmentDTO mapToApi(Appointment appointment){
        return AppointmentDTO.builder()
                .status(appointment.getStatus())
                .consumerId(appointment.getConsumerId())
                .providerId(appointment.getProviderId())
                .startDate(appointment.getStartDate())
                .endDate(appointment.getEndDate())
                .duration(appointment.getDuration())
                .businessId(appointment.getBusinessId())
                .appointmentId(appointment.getAppointmentId())
                .facilityId(appointment.getFacilityId())
                .description(appointment.getDescription())
                .officeId(appointment.getOfficeId())
                .pmsId(appointment.getPmsId())
                .build();
    }

    public static Appointment mapToDb(com.kafka.avro.model.appointment.Appointment avroAppointment) {
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
        appointment.setAppointmentId(avroAppointment.getBase().getGuid());
        appointment.setConsumerId(avroAppointment.getConsumerGuid().orElse(null));
        if(avroAppointment.getStatus().isPresent()){
            AppointmentStatus status = AppointmentStatus.valueOf(avroAppointment.getStatus().get().name());
            appointment.setStatus(status);
        }else{
            appointment.setStatus(AppointmentStatus.UNSPECIFIED);
        }
        appointment.setPmsId(avroAppointment.getBase().getPmsId());
        appointment.setDescription(avroAppointment.getDescription().orElse(NO_DESCRIPTION));
        appointment.setOfficeId(avroAppointment.getOfficeId().orElse(null));
        appointment.setProviderId(avroAppointment.getProvider().orElse(null));
        appointment.setBusinessId(avroAppointment.getBase().getBusinessGuid());
        avroAppointment.getAppointmentCodes().ifPresent(appointmentCodes -> appointmentCodes.forEach(appointmentCode -> appointment.getAppointmentProcedures().add(mapToProcedure(appointmentCode))));
        avroAppointment.getDate().ifPresent(instant ->{
            ZonedDateTime startDate = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
            ZonedDateTime endDate = null;
            int duration = avroAppointment.getDuration().orElse(0);
            appointment.setDuration(duration);
            appointment.setStartDate(startDate);
            if(duration>0){
                endDate = startDate.plus(duration, TimeUnit.HOURS.toChronoUnit());
            }
            appointment.setEndDate(endDate);
        });
        appointment.setFacilityId(avroAppointment.getFacilityId().orElse(NO_FACILITY));
        return appointment;
    }

    public static Appointment mapToDb(AppointmentDTO appointmentDTO) {
       Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
       appointment.setAppointmentId(appointmentDTO.getAppointmentId());
       appointment.setEndDate(appointmentDTO.getEndDate());
       appointment.setStartDate(appointmentDTO.getStartDate());
       appointment.setPmsId(appointmentDTO.getPmsId());
       appointment.setFacilityId(appointmentDTO.getFacilityId());
       appointment.setBusinessId(appointmentDTO.getBusinessId());
       appointment.setConsumerId(appointmentDTO.getConsumerId());
       appointment.setDuration(appointmentDTO.getDuration());
       appointment.setOfficeId(appointmentDTO.getOfficeId());
       appointment.setStatus(appointmentDTO.getStatus());
       appointment.setProviderId(appointmentDTO.getProviderId());
       return appointment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> some Spring/Avro auto-magical way of doing this?

Short answer - Yes, but only if you use the [Kafka Connect JDBC Sink](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/index.html) instead with a Schema Registry. This utilizes Connect API's internal Schema/Struct models to create database DDL statements. It'll work for more than just Avro, too.

If your data in the topic doesn't map *exactly* to the format that you want in the database, you can still use Spring-Kafka / Spring-Cloud Streams to consume & map the data to an output topic that the Connect Sink will eventually write. Or, you can use built-in /  custom `transforms` in the Connect API.

---

Otherwise, if you insist on using Spring and your own code, you need to (re)build that ORM layer yourself (as well as any database client handling, batching, error-processing, etc.). [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) is a useful Java library, I've found for converting your event models into domain/persistence models.